# How to override the print function with wrapper while changing stdout

Tags: python, oop, logging, overriding, stdout

I am trying to build a wrapper that has the following goals:

1. To catch the prints for any function to save them for later ( let's return a list for the moment )
2. To override the prints also in the wrapped functions to add a timestamp for better logging and more information ( I don't want to log.info() because this implies to change the prints in the wrapped function, and if I want to do that in the wrapper later I will lose the precision of the time )

the goal is always to not change anything in the wrapped function, aside than only to wrap them

Here is my code so far:

```
def my_decorator(func):
    def wrapped_func(*args,**kwargs):
         return func("Here we add a timestamp",*args,**kwargs)
    return wrapped_func

def list_prints_to_logs(list_prints):
    for log in list_prints:
        logger.info(log)

def my_handler(func):
    def wrapper(*args,**kwargs):

        print('this is BEFORE the function')
        old_print = print                        
        print = my_decorator(print)

        ### catching the outputs of the function
        old_stdout = sys.stdout
        sys.stdout = tempstdout = StringIO()
        results = func(*args,**kwargs)  # THE ERROR STARTS IN HERE AFTER ENTERING THIS FUNCTION
        sys.stdout = old_stdout


        print('this is AFTER the function')
        prints_in_function = tempstdout.getvalue().splitlines()
        list_prints_to_logs(prints_in_function)  

        #trying to return the print like it was before
        print = old_print 
        print(*prints_in_function, sep='\n')        

        return results
    return wrapper


@my_handler
def my_func(arg=1,kwarg='yes'):

    print('this is inside the Function')
    print('this is second print in the function')


my_func()
```

and the error that is returned to me is :

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'print' referenced before assignment
```

the line of the error has started from the print inside my_func

I am facing difficulty in how to override a function temporarily, and persist this override for the next calls,

Comment: Add `global print` at first line of `def wrapper(..):`

Comment: okey this is the answer.. dont hesitate to post it so I would mark it as an answer
Thank you

Comment: I posted the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UnboundLocalError` is caused when you had assigned local variable but used it before assingment.
Normaly when you use *assignment statement* in function, it binds a local variable.
If you want to bind gloabl variable, you should use `global` statement before assinging.

```py
def my_handler(func):
    def wrapper(*args,**kwargs):
        global print
        ...
        print = my_decorator(print)
        ...
        print = old_print 
        print(*prints_in_function, sep='\n')        

        return results
    return wrapper
```

However, this decorator doen't affect to outside of module. If you want to affect including other modules, you should rebind `builtins.print`.

```py
import builtins
def my_handle(func):
    def wrapper(*args,**kwargs):
        ...
        builtins.print = my_decorator(print)
        ...
        builtins.print = old_print
        ...
    return wrapper
```

Comment: Thank you ! this has solved the problem..
when we use builtins.print you mean that we can import this module from other modules so we can change the prints? otherwise it can't work if we don't use this builtins ?

Comment: No if you override `builtins.print`, it affect when you use `print`. python name resolution priority is _local_ - _nonlocal_ - _global_ - _builtin_. When you did not define name `print` in _local_, _nonlocal_, or _global_, it invoke `builtins.print`.